# How change the font on a canvas with a variable?

Tags: variables, canvas, fonts, tkinter

I just can't figure this one out??

```
from Tkinter import *

root=Tk()
rndfont=StringVar()

rndfont=("Purisa", 10)
def change():
   rndfont=("Purisa", 20, "bold")

canvas=Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_text(50, 20, font=(rndfont), text="change")

button1 = Button(canvas, text = "change font", command = change, anchor = W)
button1.configure(width = 10, activebackground = "#33B5E5", relief = FLAT)
button1_window = canvas.create_window(50, 50, anchor=NW, window=button1)
root.mainloop()
```

Seems like it should be simple, but im just not getting it. Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Simply assigning `rndfont` inside the function just create a local variable; no effect.

Use [`canvas.itemconfig`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.itemconfig-method) to change the font. (Before that you should save the return value of [`create_text`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_text-method)).

```
from Tkinter import *

root=Tk()

rndfont=("Purisa", 10)
def change():
   rndfont=("Purisa", 20, "bold") # --> Create local variable. Global varialbe does not change.
   canvas.itemconfig(text, font=rndfont) # <---

canvas=Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()
text = canvas.create_text(50, 20, font=(rndfont), text="change")
#^^^
button1 = Button(canvas, text = "change font", command = change, anchor = W)
button1.configure(width = 10, activebackground = "#33B5E5", relief = FLAT)
button1_window = canvas.create_window(50, 50, anchor=NW, window=button1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you SOOOO much! I tried using global variables, but im afraid i overcomplicated it. Again, thank you.

Comment: Why are you setting rndfont to a StringVar, and then immediately changing it to a tuple?

Comment: @BryanOakley, The code comes from OP's code. I removed the `StringVar`. Thank you for comment.